# Createing two entries db and db is related

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I create two entries in a db:

```
$new_user = new User();
$em->persist($new_user);

$new_friends = new UserFriends ();
$new_friends->setUserId($new_user);
```

Part of UserFriends-Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 * })
 */
private $user_id;
```

How can I get the id from new User() to create a new entry new UserFriends()?

Right now I do

```
$em->persist($new_user); $em->flush();
$id = $em->.....getRepository('Entity:User')->find($id);
$new_friends = new UserFriends ();
$new_friends->setId($id);
$em->persist($new_friends); $em->flush();
```

Is there a better way to do it? Instead of do another request to the db? In doctrine 1.2 it was very easy.

Answer (score 0):

After you call `$em->flush();`, calling `$new_user->getId();` should return the newly inserted id. So

```
$em->persist($new_user); 
$em->flush();
$new_friends = new UserFriends ();
$new_friends->setId($new_user->getId());
$em->persist($new_friends);
$em->flush();
```